# Time/Space Complexity - How to figure out in this function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, time-complexity, space-complexity

I need to calculate the time and space complexity for this problem, can anyone help me figure out what it is and why?

I believe the time complexity for this problem would be O(n^2) because of the 2 filter functions. Essentially, it would be similar to having 2 for-loops that iterate over the array and because they are looping for a set amount of time, we know that it will be O(n) for the first filter and adding another would make it O(n^2)?

Not sure about space complexity.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9];
const result = arr.filter(x => arr.filter(y => y === x).length > 1)
console.log(result);
// 2, 2, 4, 4, 7, 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, time complexity is `O(n^2)` - for example, if `arr` has 10 items, the algorithm needs to make ~100 comparisons before finishing.

Space complexity is `O(n)`. For example, consider the last iteration of the outer `.filter` - the `result` that's almost finished being constructed takes up `O(n)` space at that time (worst-case; equivalent to the side of the input `arr`). The inner array inside the callback being filtered (which will then have its `length` checked, and returned) will also be, worst-case, the side of the input `n`. So, the most space that will be being currently used at any point in time is `O(2n)`, which is equivalent to `O(n)`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right about the time complexity, it is O(n^2) due to the two nested loops.

IMO space complexity is O(n) as you need only n units of space to keep the array and no additional memory is allocated.

Comment: appreciate the confirmation